# Expand/Collapse Grid

Tags: xaml, windows-10-universal

I am trying to Collapse/Expand Grid with animation and while it's animating move all other components accordingly.

So far I used

```
<ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin" Storyboard.TargetName="GridName">
     <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.59" Value="0,0,0,0" />
     (...more frames)
</ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames >
```

But the effect is far from acceptable (animation not smooth). I was wandering if the new controls has such options? I also came across some Expanding/Collapsing ListViews - but they did not work with which contains data.

Edit: I tried animating the heights property - but nothing happen (no error and no visible result). Below my code:

```
<Storyboard x:Name="MainImageSlideOut">
        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:1" To="0" 
                             Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height" 
                             Storyboard.TargetName="Grid" 
                             EnableDependentAnimation="True"/>

</Storyboard>
<Storyboard x:Name="MainImageSlideIn">
        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:1" To="250" 
                             Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height" 
                             Storyboard.TargetName="Grid" 
                             EnableDependentAnimation="True"/>

</Storyboard>

....

<Grid Background="#171717">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Grid Grid.Row="1" 
          Height="250"
          x:Name="Grid" 
          Background="#202020" />            

    <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="2">
    ...
    </ScrollViewer>

</Grid>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a similar functionality in my application.
the way I use it is by using `ScaleTransform` here is an example:

```
<Storyboard x:Key="gridLoading">
    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[0].(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)" Storyboard.TargetName="IAmGroot">
        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="1">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                <CubicEase EasingMode="EaseOut"/>
            </EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
        </EasingDoubleKeyFrame>
    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[0].(ScaleTransform.ScaleY)" Storyboard.TargetName="IAmGroot">
        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="1"/>
     </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
</Storyboard>
```

This will load the grid from the middle of the screen and expand it to fit the screen.
If you want to perform an animation on all of the elements then this animation will do the trick, however if you need different behavior you will probably have to handle animation for the items inside of your `Grid` separately.
HTH

Comment: Il looks perfectly - but under the grid I am trying to animate there is another grid that should take current grid's place. Unfortunetly it doesn't. Both Grids are inside main grid that has row definistions Auto for first and * for second.

Comment: One way to for this would be to manipulate the height of one of the Grids, then the other would automatically resize it self to fit the content, that means only one animation instead of 2. Are the Grids in the same Row?

Comment: ok, So when one of the Grid is visible the other one has to take it's place, but they can't be visible both at the same time.

Comment: After animating Height nothing happened.I edited my question with more details.

Comment: Have you tried using `Blend` for creating that animation?

Comment: I have never used it - do you have page for begginers maybe?

Comment: Just go on you tube and type in blend xaml animation, and you should be good.

Comment: WOW! It works like a charm! :) thank you - it's bee very usefull.