# WPF: How to fade-in a grid on button click, and fade-out on another button click?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Here is my window XAML code:

```
<Window x:Class="WPF.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    x:Name="MainScreen"
<DockPanel>
    <!--#region Navigation-->
    <StackPanel Style="{StaticResource stlNavigationBar}">
        <!-- some buttons -->
    </StackPanel>
    <!--#endregion-->

    <!--#region Page-->
    <Grid x:Name="Page">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    </Grid>
    <!--#endregion-->
</DockPanel>
```

**How the navigation currently works:**

In the navigation, there are some buttons. Whenever the user clicks on one of them, the function `ShowPage(UserControl page)` is called from the click event, clears the `Page` grid from the current page (which is a `UserControl`), and then adds to it the desirable page:

```
public void ShowPage(UserControl page)
{
    Page.Children.Clear();
    Grid.SetRow(page, 2);
    Grid.SetColumn(page, 0);
    Page.Children.Add(page);
}
```

**How I want the navigation to work:**

The same way, except with fade-in and out animations when the user switches between pages. I cannot figure out the logic, particularly because the switch is executed in the code-behind and the animation is set in the XAML.

To summary, **how to fade-in a grid on button click, and fade-out on another button click?**

Comment: I am very new to WPF, so it is more than likely that this is a stupid question. However, I would be grateful for a serious answer.

Comment: Look into `Blend` for WPF it comes with Visual Studio. If you want some tutorials there are thousands of them on `YouTube`. HTH

Comment: @XAMlMAX - Well, I tried to use blend for this, but since I do not have a good understanding of how things works in XAML, I want to do it hard-code it first.

Comment: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35657010/2029607) is a link to one of my answers on similar subject. What you will have to find now is how to locate the `Storyboard` and start it on button click, which is going to be very easy from there.

Comment: Could you adjust the answer to fit my specific needs and post it here so I could mark it as the accepted answer?

Comment: OK. But it will take a while

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105695/discussion-between-sipo-and-xamlmax).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an animation for your `Grid` which needs to go into your `<Window.Resources>` tag:

```
<Storyboard x:Key="gridLoading">
<DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[0].(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)" Storyboard.TargetName="Page">
    <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
    <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="1">
        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
            <CubicEase EasingMode="EaseOut"/>
        </EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
    </EasingDoubleKeyFrame>
</DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
<DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[0].(ScaleTransform.ScaleY)" Storyboard.TargetName="Page">
    <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
    <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="1"/>
 </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
```

```
<Storyboard x:Key="gridLoadingBack">
<DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[0].(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)" Storyboard.TargetName="Page">
    <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1"/>
    <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="1">
        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
            <CubicEase EasingMode="EaseOut"/>
        </EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
    </EasingDoubleKeyFrame>
</DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
<DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[0].(ScaleTransform.ScaleY)" Storyboard.TargetName="Page">
    <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1"/>
    <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="1"/>
 </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
```

Now this is assigned to your `Grid` so in your click event handler you call it like so:

```
var storyBoardIn = (Storyboard)this.Resources["gridLoading"];
var storyBoardOut = (Storyboard)this.Resources["gridLoadingBack"];
//now depending on which storyboard you want to call just call Begin() method
storyBoardIn.Begin();
//or
storyBoardOut.Begin();
```

Comment: I copied the `<Storyboard>`s to the `<Window.Resources>` and the C# code to the `Button_Click_1` function, but it throws an exception "An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in PresentationFramework.dll

Additional information: '[Unknown]' property does not point to a DependencyObject in path '(0).(1)[0].(2)'."

Comment: UPDATE: I adjust your code a little bit and it works for me now. Thank you very much!