# How to make a card fade in and out C# / WPF / MaterialDesign

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

After I click a button, I'd like my card to fade in, and then after a set time fade back out. Unfortunately, I'm new to C# / WPF, and don't know how I would go about doing this. Currently I'm using MaterialDeisgn and Dragablz aswell.

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35865796/wpf-how-to-fade-in-a-grid-on-button-click-and-fade-out-on-another-button-click) solution, however it just caused my program to crash. Is someone able to help me with this? Since I'm not sure at all where to go with this, I've atatched the XAML for the Card I want to fade in / out itself (it would be triggered by clicking a different button).

EDIT FOR CLARITY: I'm trying to make it so that it starts hidden, and when an if statement in the MainWindow.xaml.cs is true, fades in, fades out after some time (maybe a second?), and then stays hidden until triggered again.

```
<materialDesign:Card

    x:Name="userFound"
    HorizontalAlignment="Center"
    VerticalAlignment="Center"
    Background="{DynamicResource PrimaryHueMidBrush}"
    Foreground="{DynamicResource PrimaryHueDarkForegroundBrush}"
    Width="81"
    Padding="8"
    materialDesign:ShadowAssist.ShadowDepth="Depth2"
    UniformCornerRadius="6" Margin="-60,0,0,249">
        <TextBlock
        TextWrapping="Wrap">
        User Found!
        </TextBlock>
</materialDesign:Card>
```

Thank you so much for any help! I'm 100% lost, so anything helps.

Comment: See that large margin you have there? That is almost always a problem when you deliver an app. The user often has a different "sized" display and large fixed margins  are then a problem. Best to use grids with proportional columns / rows and put things in their "cells". That can be a stackpanel if there's a bunch of controls. It's almost never a good plan to drag controls onto the design surface for this reason.

Answer (score 0):

This is modified from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.animation.timeline.begintime?view=netframework-4.8#System_Windows_Media_Animation_Timeline_BeginTime  and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/graphics-multimedia/how-to-animate-the-opacity-of-an-element-or-brush

```
<Button>
 <Button.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Click">
          <BeginStoryboard>
            <Storyboard>
                <DoubleAnimation BeginTime="0:0:0.0" Storyboard.TargetName="userFound" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Card.Opacity)" From="0" To="1" Duration="0:0:0.5"/> //Fade in taking half a second  
                <DoubleAnimation BeginTime="0:0:1.5" Storyboard.TargetName="userFound" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Card.Opacity)" From="1" To="0" Duration="0:0:0.5"/>//Fade out takes half a second 
            </Storyboard>
          </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
 </Button.Triggers>
<Button>
```

The above would make your card fully opaque in 1/2 a second then waits 1 full second from when the card was fully opaque and fade out   meaning all animation complete in 2 seconds

remove the button triggers and add the storyboard to page resources in then add a x:key  so it can be called from code behind

```
<Page.Resources>
        <Storyboard x:Key="Test">
            <DoubleAnimation BeginTime="0:0:0.0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" From="0" To="1" Duration="0:0:0.5"/> //Fade in taking half a second
            <DoubleAnimation BeginTime="0:0:1.5" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" From="1" To="0" Duration="0:0:0.5"/> //Fade out takes half a second
        </Storyboard>
    </Page.Resources>
```

Then like they did on [WPF Fade Out on a control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4317875/wpf-fade-out-on-a-control/4318320)  do this or something similar in the click event

```
if(truecondition)
{
((Storyboard)this.Resources["Test"]).Begin(userFound);
}
```

this is a way to do it but there are better ways. I can not currently think of them but i know they exist.

Comment: This works perfectly, but I have a question. If I want to make it so something has to validate before it animate (ie. an if statement is true in the MainWindow.xaml.cs), how would I make it so it doesnt animate unless returned true?

Comment: are you talking about in a click event in the code behind file?

Comment: Yes - when the button is clicked it checks to see if there's a username within a string. userFound is a card that pops up saying "User Found!", so I was hoping to make it so that the card will only fade in / out if the user is found in the string.

Comment: edited my answer  but better answers will come from somewhere else i need to become better myself

Comment: I’ll make sure to try this tomorrow - one question though.

Would I add the page resources to the MainWindow.xaml or the App.xaml? Asking because I tried a solution where I added a <Window.Resource> to the MainWindow.xaml and it got rid of all of the MaterialDesign/Dragablz stuff I was using, but adding it to the App.xaml preserves it, but it didn’t work.

Comment: @leonjacobh  were you able to get it to work?